# Deploy/Dockerize React + FastAPI using Nginx

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize and deploy React frontend and FastAPI backend using Nginx via Docker. Following are my files:

Dockerfile.backend

```
FROM python:3.11 

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt /app
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 8000:8000

# start the server
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

Dockerfile.frontend

```
FROM --platform=linux/x86_64 node:18.16.0 as build-step

WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install
COPY . ./

RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine


COPY --from=build-step /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

nginx.default.conf

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/;

    index index.html;


    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.backend
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  frontend:
    build: 
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.frontend
    container_name: frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
```

File structure:

```
─── Application/
    ├── backend/
    │   ├── main.py
    │   ├── Dockerfile.backend
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   └── src/
    │       └── .. Related files ..
    ├── frontend/
    │   ├── package.json
    │   ├── package-lock.json
    │   ├── Dockerfile.frontend
    │   ├── nginx.default.conf
    │   └── src/
    │       └── .. Related files ..
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    └── backend.env
```

I am building the docker images like this:
`docker-compose build --no-cache`

And then running the server via:
`docker-compse up`

I am able to run the backend on: localhost:8000. But I am unable to run the frontend on 3000 or 80.

I keep getting these logs in the Terminal:

```
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
frontend  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
frontend  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
frontend  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.24.0
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.1 20220924 (Alpine 12.2.1_git20220924-r4)
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit-pr
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
frontend  | 2023/08/10 08:50:09 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
```

3000 port is accessible, but it loads the static HTML file from React

I tried to change ports, expose the endpoint in Nginx frontend, expose the volumes. But I guess I am missing something. Backend is fine and working as expected.

But I am missing something or some port mis-connection which is not able to serve the React application. How can I fix this?